# Filter By Looked Up Value In Cgridview

Tags: yii

My early days of Yii. Have searched and can't find any clues on this hence post. I have modified the admin.php layout to lookup values from a couple of related tables as follows

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'silo-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            array(
                    'name'=>'silo_id',
                    'value'=>'$data->silo->name',
                    'header'=>'Parent',
            ),
            'name',
            array(
                    'name'=>'silo_type',
                    'value'=>'$data->siloType?$data->siloType->type:"no silo type"',
            ),
            array(
                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

This is great and all works ... apart from the fact that the filter fields are still looking up the numerical values rather than the text values (e.g. I want to filter on a text 'description' rather than the UID that represents that description).

How do I go about changing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick method would be to use drop down lists instead of text fields for the filter fields. You could populate this as follows

```
'name'=>'silo_id',
....
'filter'=>CHtml::listDataEx(Silo::model()->findAll(),'id','name')
```

A longer trickier method is to alter your query to include a search for the foreign field. You would need to store the search term. For a single such field you would need to

1. Add a public field to your model say $silo_name
2. Set this field to safe in your model's `rules()` method
3. Set the required columns filter to

   ```
   'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model,'silo_name')
   ```
4. Finally edit your model's `search()` method to reflect the above

   ```
   $criteria->together=true;//perform a single query
   $criteria->with=array('silo'=>array('id','name'));//specify which relations to add to the query
   $criteria->compare('silo.name',$this->silo_name,true);//$silo_name is a public field
   ```